# c++ conditional expression assign reference

Tags: c++

```
using namespace std;
class A {
    public:
        virtual int r();
};

class B : public A {
    public:
        int r() { return 1; }
};

class C : public A {
    public:
        int r() { return 2;}
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    B b;
    C c;
    A &a = argc > 1 ? b : c;
    return a.r();
}
```

with errors:

```
#g++ a.cc
a.cc: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
a.cc:20:18: error: operands to ‘?:’ have different types ‘B’ and ‘C’
   20 |  A &a = argc > 1 ? b : c;
      |         ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
```

How can I fix it to bind the reference to either of the two objects?

Comment: The ternary operator (`?:`)  requires the one of the two possible results (`b` and `c`) to be able to be converted to the type of the other.  Neither of classes `B` and `C` (or references to them) can be implicitly converted to the other.    The fact that both derive from `A` does not change that.   You need to change the expression so one of the possible results can be converted to the type of the other.

Comment: @Peter "to be able to be converted" -> "to be able to be statically converted" If I recall correctly, the Python conditional operator requires only that the types are related dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

It's just the way the language works, that's all. Note that you can't `static_cast` from a `B` to a `C` either (or vice-versa) which, informally speaking, is required for the branch types of the ternary conditional operator.

You need to write something like

```
A &a = argc > 1 ? static_cast<A&>(b) : static_cast<A&>(c);
```

Comment: If it makes you feel less pressured, I hate both :P

Comment: Chat was not with me.

Comment: As a note, only one cast is needed (either for `b` or `c`) even if I find it is clearer with both.

Comment: can i dynamic create b or c , instead of create all of them ? if only use stack allocation